# calling a youtube playlist in a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I am trying to develop a scenario where I would be creating different play lists in youtube by grouping a bunch of videos and call them as video thumbnails in different product pages of an e commerce website. The idea is to associate a set of videos to a product. When I click the thumbnail I would open the video as a popup. How should I tackle it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you searched previous similar questions?

See if this helps: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-to-get-thumbnail-of-youtube-video-link-using-youtube-api)

The only diference is you want to use a full playlist, I guess

Comment: one thing already like about you is you are a metallica fan ;-). Thanks for the link.